# how to strike and unstrike in arraylist

Tags: java, android

I am trying to be able to strike and unstrike an item that has been added to an array list. however iam unable to unstrike it. I tried putting the code into an if statement but cannot get it to work.

please can someone assist?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

List<String> toDoList;
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
ListView listView;


EditText editText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toDoList = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.list_view_layout,toDoList);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.id_list_view);

    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) view;
                    if (textView.getPaintFlags() > 0) {
                        textView.setPaintFlags(textView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                    }
                    else {
                        textView.setPaintFlags(textView.getPaintFlags() & (~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
                    }




            }
    });
```

The setOnItemClickListener does strike through the item when it is clicked the first time, however when the item is clicked again, it does not unstrike the item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     TextView textView = (TextView) view;
     textView.setPaintFlags(textView.getPaintFlags() ^ Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
}
```

Comment: Hi Kasim, this seemed to work, thank you for the advice, can you advise what the '^' symbol does?

Comment: Java XOR operator, represented by the ^ symbol. It's a bitwise operator — that is, an operator comparing the matching bits of two values in order to return a result. In the XOR case, if two bits of the same position have the same value, the resulting bit will be 0. Otherwise, it'll be 1